# Three20: No such file or directory found

Tags: ios, ios4, three20

in the last 4 hours I try to add Three20 to my iOS poject.
I try to avoid it a long time but now I am on a point in which i can't :)

So I added it correctly all to my projects and after around 2 hours of work it compile perfectly!!!

Badly, I got a "No such file or directory found"-error when try to

```
#import "Three20/Three20.h"
```

I try nearly every string in the "Header search paths" I can imagine to get this working, but I have no idea...

here is a screenshot of my directory listing:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yWjM.png

here is my Header search paths:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXEWP.png

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the three20 framework manually or using the included ttmodule.py script? The script usually takes care of everything. You can either import the framework into an old xcode3 or current xcode4 based project. The python script is located in `src/scripts/`

Comment: I had done it manuelly and it works (except the header things)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: everything. Three20 has a very clear documentation. Just follow the **Adding Three20 to your project** section from https://github.com/facebook/three20

Comment: I followed them, I tried the readme there and everything except the header search paths is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

At least for Xcode 4.2 and 4.3, you should do a previous step before you click on Product->Archive. This step is clicking on: Product -> Build for -> Build for archiving.

Answer (score 0):

In USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS in Build Setting under the Search Paths section add this:

$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../three20

$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../three20